# Disabling A Form Element To Refresh?

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET Listview Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299021/net-listview-refresh)

I'm adding 50k~ish items to a  list view and it refreshes each time (this is slowing it down big time).  How can I disable the redrawing of the form, and enable it when it's done adding all of the items?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299021/net-listview-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

How about adding it to a collection and binding this collection to the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource(v=VS.100).aspx) property of the list control only once:

```
IList<Foo> items = FetchFoos();
myList.DataSource = items;
```

Of course if fetching 50k items is slow you might consider a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to avoid freezing the UI (as a user I hate when my UI freezes).

Comment: By collection do you mean array?

Comment: Anything that implements IList, could be an array if you will.